# Exercise 5.37 in Fulton

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose $C$ is a nonsingular plane projective cubic. This exercise starts by assuming that $O$ is a flex, and first asks to prove that the points of $C$ of order $3$ in $C$ are precisely the flexes other than $O$, and that together with $O$ they form a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(3)\times \mathbb{Z}/(3)$. This is not hard.

It then goes on to ask for a proof that the points of order 2 (together with $O$) form a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(2)\times \mathbb{Z}/(2)$. This is also not hard to show.

So, **First question:** From that, can we conclude (since the structure of the group is independent of the basepoint) that no matter which basepoint we choose (whether it is a flex or not) there are three points of order 2 which, together with the basepoint, form a Klein 4-group?  (Of course, the identity of these points changes when the basepoint changes.)

The final part of the exercise asks: "Let $C$ be a nonsingular cubic, $P\in C$. How many lines through $P$ are tangent to $C$ at some point $Q\ne P$? (The answer depends on whether $P$ is a flex.)" It's the final parenthetical comment that I don't understand. If my first question is correct, then given a point $P$, set $O=P$. There are then exactly three lines from $P$ that are tangent to a point $Q$ other than $P$: the lines through the points of order 2. So **Second question:** Why is the answer dependent on whether $P$ is a flex or not? (I understand DCT's comment, and it makes sense [assuming you can find one such $Q$], but I don't see where my arguments fail.)

*Edited* to respond to DCT's comment below and to clarify my confusion.

Comment: I think the issue is the condition $Q\neq P$? There should be four such lines for general $P$ (because you need to divide by 2 to solve and you have just shown that there are 4 points of order 2). But if $P$ is a flex, then one of those lines is the tangent line at $P$, so there are only three.

Comment: @DCT I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Can you tell me what's wrong with my argument in paragraphs 2 and 3?

Comment: I think you're argument is right, except you should have 4 lines? If $2Q=-P$, there are always 4 solutions for $Q$ (given any element $A$ of order 2, $2(Q+A)=2Q$). However, $Q=P$ is a solution iff $P$ is a flex.

Comment: Oh, at the very beginning, when you choose your basepoint $O$, it has to be a flex for the group law to make sense. (Since $O$ is the zero element, $3O=0$, so it has to be a flex.)

Comment: @DCT Why *must* $O$ be a flex? I understand that it's convenient, but even if it's not, we still have $2O=O$, since $2O$ is computed by finding the third point $P$ at which the tangent at $O$ intersects the curve, and then the third point at which the line from $P$ to $O$ intersects the curve. This is clearly $O$.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right about the choosing the basepoint to not be a flex (http://math.uga.edu/~pete/EllipticCurves.pdf page 6), I didn't know that was okay.

Comment: So did you ever get an answer to this? Specifically to how many lines from P are tangent to another point of the curve when P is not flex?

Comment: @JKEG I did not. Do you have one? :)

Comment: @rogerl Yes! (https://www.overleaf.com/read/kgyxszthnsxp, see part 6 specifically). There is only one detail missing (if you fill it you're my hero) and it's that I don't have a proof that the $Q$ used there exists.

Answer (score 0):

This document of mine will hopefully answer 95% of your question: https://www.overleaf.com/read/kgyxszthnsxp.